# append not inserting values

Tags: php, jquery, file, append

here my problem is the values that are selected through append are not getting inserted in to the post value..here am pasting my code

```
      <div id="update_new_<?php echo $value->id;?>" class="update_new_<?php echo $value->id;?>">
            <div class="form-group mb0" style="margin-bottom: 0px">
                <label for="field-1"
                       class="col-sm-4 control-label">Other Document</label>
                <div class="col-sm-5">
                    <div class="fileinput fileinput-new" data-provides="fileinput">
                        <?php
                        if (!empty($value->documents)) {
                            $uploaded_file = json_decode($value->documents);
                        }
                        if (!empty($uploaded_file)):foreach ($uploaded_file as $v_files_image): ?>
                            <div class="">
                                <input type="hidden" name="fileName[]"
                                       value="<?php echo $v_files_image ?>">

                                <span class=" btn btn-default btn-file">
                                <span class="fileinput-filename"> <?php echo $v_files_image ?></span>
                                <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="remCFile" style="float: none;">×</a>
                                </span>
                                <strong>
                                    <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="RCF"><i
                                            class="fa fa-times"></i>&nbsp;Remove</a></strong>
                                <p></p>
                            </div>

                        <?php endforeach; ?>
                        <?php else: ?>
                            <span class="btn btn-default btn-file"><span
                                    class="fileinput-new">Select File</span>
                                                        <span class="fileinput-exists"><?= lang('change') ?></span>
                                                        <input type="file" name="files[]">
                                                    </span>
                            <span class="fileinput-filename"></span>
                            <a href="#" class="close fileinput-exists" data-dismiss="fileinput"
                               style="float: none;">&times;</a>
                        <?php endif; ?>
                    </div>
                    <div id="msg_pdf" style="color: #e11221"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-3">
                    <strong><a href="javascript:void(0);" id="update_more" onclick="add_field('<?php echo $value->id;?>');" u_id="<?php echo $value->id;?>" class="addCF update_more_<?php echo $value->id;?>"><i
                                class="fa fa-plus"></i>&nbsp;Add More
                        </a></strong>
                </div>
            </div>



        </div>
```

here is my script please have a look

```
<script type="text/javascript">

 var maxAppends = 0;
 function add_field(id)
 {

      var update_new = $('<div class="form-group" style="margin-bottom: 0px">\n\
             <label for="field-1" class="col-sm-4 control-label">Documentsss</label>\n\
 <div class="col-sm-5">\n\
 <div class="fileinput fileinput-new" data-provides="fileinput">\n\
       <span class="btn btn-default btn-file"><span class="fileinput-new">Select file</span><span class="fileinput-exists" >Change</span><input type="file" name="files[]" ></span> <span class="fileinput-filename"></span><a href="#" class="close fileinput-exists" data-dismiss="fileinput" style="float: none;">&times;</a></div></div>\n\<div class="col-sm-2">\n\<strong>\n\<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="remCF"><i class="fa fa-times"></i>&nbsp;Remove</a></strong></div>');
     maxAppends++;

     $(".update_new_"+id).append(update_new);


   }
   </script>
```

Here while clicking to add more fields its coming correctly but the values selected in that field is not getting while passing the value through post and i have a doubt that if it is caused by using dynamic way off adding the data.
The problem i figured out is the problem is the `<div id="update_new_<?php echo $value->id;?>">` is inside a foreach loop so how can we done this with in a foreach loop.

Comment: You have `var update_new = $('<...html...>');` in your script, don't you just mean: `var update_new = '<...html...>'`? Why surround it with `$()`?

Comment: i had done in that way too..but result is same

Comment: Then check your [developer tools](https://www.browserstack.com/developer-tools), use the debugger to see what your Javascript is doing.

Comment: its not showing any error

Comment: the problem is the `<div id="update_new_<?php echo $value->id;?>">` is inside a foreach loop so how can we done this with in a foreach loop

Comment: any body have any idea of using append a div to foreach loop

Answer (score 0):

In your script, change `.update_new_` to `#update_new_`